# How to use linq.js except

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am trying to use linq.js to remove a object from a array. I am customizing highcharts and i need to modify the series. I identified the object I want to remove using .where. When I run it through the Except it is not throwing any errors. it just doesn't filter the object out.

object that I want to remove from the series

```
var matchingSeries = Enumerable.From(series).Where('x => x.options.id == "' + item + '"').First();
```

trying to get this to work

```
 var newSeries = Enumerable.From(series).Except(matchingSeries).ToArray();
```

I would like to use the id as the identifier. the id is nested in matchingSeries.options.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ in C#, `Except` deals with two lists.  Remove the `First()` call from your first statement to return a list of items that can be matched against the first list.

Comment: the first statement is how i get the series I need to remove

Comment: Understand, but the API is meant to be the same.  If it doesn't work for the OP, I'll remove the answer.  I don't have time to run it.

Comment: `First` returns a single item.  If you are wanting multiple items, then you don't want that anyway.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect.the action you took